# Dash and C: eval "$(<cmdfile)" and system("eval \"\$(<cmdfile)\"") giving different results

Tags: c, shell, command-line, eval, dash-shell

I would like to use the *system()* function in C to evaluate an expression within a file *cmdfile* but I'm not getting the same results as when I do so on the command line directly. The content of *cmdfile* is the following:

```
$ cat cmdfile
echo hello
```

and when I evaluate its content on the command line directly, it works:

```
$ eval "$(<cmdfile)"
hello
```

To do the same in C, I'm using system(). This is my code:

```
$ cat systest.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* cmd = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", cmd);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

The trouble is that I don't see any output when using the above code:

```
$ ./systest "eval \"\$(<cmdfile)\""
eval "$(<cmdfile)"
```

There should be *hello* printed right after the printf output but it doesn't work. Still, I know that system() is definitely doing something, because if I give it a non-existing filename, dash complains:

```
$ ./systest "eval \"\$(<cmdfileFF)\""
eval "$(<cmdfileFF)"
sh: 1: cannot open cmdfileFF: No such file
```

and if I just evaluate *echo hello* without involving *cmdfile*, it works too:

```
$ ./systest "eval \"echo hello\""
eval "echo hello"
hello
```

I'd like to know what is causing this difference in behaviour. Is there any other way of executing the content of *cmdfile* in dash? I'm restricted to only using the built-in commands of dash on the command line, so options such as `./systest "eval \"\$(cat cmdfile)\""` are not possible. Further, the expansion of `"$(<cmdfile)"` should only happen within system(), not before (thus `./systest "eval \"$(<cmdfile)\""` won't work.

I tested this with dash 0.5.10.2-6 and dash 0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2.

Thank you for any insight!

### Edit

Thanks to  Jonathan Leffler's comment, I now realise that dash doesn't understand the `$(<file)` syntax. So what would be a dash-compatible equivalent?

### Wrap-up

So my confusion was due to the fact that system(...) always uses /bin/sh, but when testing my expressions on the command line, I was accidentally invoking bash instead of dash. Hence the results were different.

Comment: `$(<file)` is a Bash extension over POSIX shell.  I would expect Dash to complain or misunderstand it.  Note that `system` runs `sh` judging from the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @JonathanLeffler. /bin/sh (and /usr/bin/sh) are sym links pointing to dash on my system. If dash doesn't understand $(<file), what would be the posix-compatible equivalent..?

Comment: Why the back-slash in front of the `$`?

Comment: The POSIX equivalent of `$(<file)` is `$(cat file)`.  And if you can only use Dash built-in commands, you are probably stuck. Who imposed that restriction on you and why? It is absurd.

Comment: @alk, so that the expression within the brackets only gets expanded in system(), not before.

Comment: I expected the C compiler to complain about the escaped `$`.

Comment: @alk — the C compiler doesn’t see the dollar sign, escaped or unescaped. The C runtime might see it; it depends on what the she’ll does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ah well yes, I assumed this went literally into the C code. Which it probably does not.

Comment: So @Kirjain: How do you call the compiled C program?

Comment: Using single quotes around the argument probably makes life easier than using double quotes. There’s no need to escape anything except single quotes. Make sure you see what is being passed to you program.  Add `fflush(stdout);` before the call to `system()`.

Comment: @alk, I'm calling it as follows: `$ ./systest "eval \"\$(<cmdfile)\""`

Comment: Nitpicking: you don’t need `<string.h>` but you do need `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I *think* dot-sourcing is equivalent to `eval`…? `./systest '. ./cmdfile'`

Comment: @oguzismail I wanted to read the file without changing the rights. I just tested Ry- 's suggestion and it does seem to work with my version of dash. So I guess that's the only option for me for now. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Ry-, your version did work for me. If you want to type it into an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: `system` **always** runs `/bin/sh`, that's what POSIX says. Depending on things it might be more or less strictly POSIX-compliant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(< …)` substitution isn’t POSIX-sh-compatible, but your sh is restricted to about that. A general alternative is to replace `< cmdfile` with `cat cmdfile`:

```sh
./systest "eval \"\$(cat cmdfile)\""
```

but I think [dot-sourcing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) is equivalent in this case:

```sh
./systest '. ./cmdfile'
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper fix is to put a shebang line in the script and mark it as executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"
```

The shebang needs to be the absolutely first line of the file (its first two bytes should be `#` and `!`). The quoting around the argument to `echo` is not strictly necessary here, but good practice. (See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable))

Changing the permissions only needs to be done once, when you have just created the file:

```
chmod +x ./cmdfile
```

Now, you can simply use

```
system("./cmdfile")
```